# Segfault when assign values to sparse matrix by multi-threads

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I intend to fill a sparse matrix with values which are derived from series of steps, to make it more efficient, OpenMP is used to speed up those processes, I find it works fine when using 1 thread, but caught segfault for multi-threads, I prepared a simple demo code to  reproduce the error, sincerely hope someone could do me a favour.

```r
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(bigmemory, BH)]]

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::sp_mat test(arma::vec x, int n, int threads = 1){
    omp_set_num_threads(threads);
    arma::sp_mat m(n, n);
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            m(i, j) = x[i * n + j];
        }
    }
    return m;
}

# run 
a<-test(sample(c(0,1,2),100*100,rep=T), n=100, threads=1)
a<-test(sample(c(0,1,2),100*100,rep=T), n=100, threads=10)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a pure C++ program?

Comment: Please don't cross post.  Decide ahead if you post it here, or as an issue at GH. Not both. Reference:  https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/274

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tl;dr:* You can't.

Longer story:  One of the key advantages of (Rcpp)Armadillo is the very nice and consistent API on top of underlying operations which are somewhere between confusing and hard to use.  One the disadvantages is that we easily loose sight of the underlying data structures.

*Dense* matrices are (essentially always) fixed chunks of memory.  In essence, a vector of size rows x columns.  This is what allows us the efficient 'zero copy' transfer between R and (Rcpp)Armadillo. It also allows us to work concurrently on non-overlapping chunks.  That's a big deal, and *e.g.* RcppParallel takes full advantage of it. OpenMP works here.

*Sparse* matrices are (and I simplify here) dynamic list/vector types with interdependence.  So concurrent work simply cannot work.  Sad. But that is what it is. It becomes clear once you look more closely at the common data structures for sparse matrices (as *e.g.* R's Matrix package does).  And for example [this wikipedia piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) is a pretty decent and thorough introduction.

Comment: Dear Dirk, thank you very much for the detail explanations, very useful and fully addressed the issue.